# C# dll references produce a classnotfound exception

Tags: c#, java, dll, noclassdeffounderror, ikvm

I used IKVM to convert slf4j to dll's for use in a c# program. It's throwing me an exception. (NoClassDefFoundError was unhandled org.slf4j.LoggerFactory)

The code is as follows

```
acceptor = new SocketAcceptor();
connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler();
serverlistenerPort = 32156;
SocketAcceptorConfig sac = new SocketAcceptorConfig();
sac.getSessionConfig().setTcpNoDelay(false);
sac.setReuseAddress(true);
sac.setBacklog(100);

//The following line is what seems to hate me.
acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverlistenerPort), connectionHandler, sac);
```

Connection Handler is a class I have that overrides IoHandler(a mina class) I have triple checked that I have all the IKVM dll's referenced, and I've searched every possible combination of terms on Google for a solution, but when all the solutions are for Java and they just need to reference .jar files. I'm certain I have all the .dll's referenced (This works as a java program using jars)

Comment: How you have compile your jar file to a dll? Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used this command to get the dll compiled:

```
ikvmc -sharedclassloader file1.jar ...... file8.jar
```

should be OK for what I've read, shouldn't it?

And then used this to get the dll into the global cache:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64> gacutil -i "C:\ikvm-7.1.4532.2\bin\IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll"
```

and same command to put all the partial libraries needed